# Calculating bounds of a "dirty rectangle"

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I'm following [noita's GDC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prXuyMCgbTc) (10:30 is where the talk becomes relevant to what I'm doing) to implement various optimization techniques for my falling sand simulation.

The one that's currently blocking me is dirty rects, where a rectangle is stored inside each chunk that covers the area that needs to be updated. The purpose of this is to reduce the amount of particles you have to iterate over for each chunk each frame.

Currently, I'm able to create the bounds when a new particle is placed, but the tricky part seems to be shrinking the dirty rect when a particle moves/replaced with air.

Here's a gif showcasing what I currently have

[image]

As can be seen in the gif, the rectangle expands to accommodate newly placed particles, but does not shrink when they're erased (erasing is just replacing that particle with an air particle).

What's the most efficient way to calculate a new bounds when a particle is replaced?

In the GDC, the developer says that even if you don't multi-thread the simulation, the dirty rect is still supposed to give a performance boost due to how much it reduces the amount of particles you have to iterate over each frame during the update of the simulation, so is something that is supposed to increase performance and thus needs to be done in somewhat of an efficient manner.

(People have told me that I don't need to do this in the first place, perhaps due to a misunderstanding of the simulation I'm creating, which I feel is wrong, because in my profiling I've found that the game starts losing FPS when updating multiple chunks even when those chunks don't have any particles to update because of just the sheer amount it has to iterate over even if it's skipping all of them)

If anyone has any insight on this that would be great (code examples would be amazing, too) because I've been trying to figure this out for days without any progress due to how obscure this optimization method is.

Comment: This is a classic example of a problem that can be efficiently solved in one direction, but not the other. You can improve the time to find the reduced bounds with sorted lists or  maybe quad trees, but those add additional time in other ways. Before going that route, does it bottleneck if you rebuild the dirty rect from scratch? Given that Noita is already subdividing & threading, I suspect they are taking advantage of partitioning & brute-forcing the bounds.

Comment: Why wouldn't replacing the sand with air make the rect dirty?

Comment: "Dirty" rectangles are usually supposed to be ephemeral. It should not take too long until you turn them into "clean" rectangles by applying them to the underlying data and then disposing of them.

Answer (score 1):

I've been thinking about this myself. First of all, the dirty rect as far as I understand is reset to zero every time the 64x64 chunk is rendered. Before that, anything that changes the actual color during the simulation step increases the size of the dirty rect. This should include you "erasing" stuff by drawing space. Doing this makes it so you don't have to update every pixel color of your texture each step. I never heard of a dirty rect before watching that awesome YouTube video though, so I may be totally confused.

As far as the time it takes to loop over all of the pixels in the world for the purpose of updating mechanics and physics, I would set a counter for each chunk that represents how many dynamic pixels it has in it and increment/decrement it when things get drawn in or swapped to another chunk. Then you only have to update the chunks with counts greater than zero. I think that's the optimization you're looking for. I don't know if it's actually better. I'm going to implement it in my own sand sim and find out.

However, I'm actually totally wrong about everything, if you slow down the video at 10:41 you can see that Petri erases the stone and no dirty rect is drawn. Also earlier he says that this method allows you to not have to "test" every pixel, not "draw". So I have just as many questions as OP.

So it looks like you can just save a copy of the previous update's dirty rect and build the next update rects from nothing. Include everything around dynamic elements that swap with each other, elements in freefall, and any element that is created from thin air. There are some artifacts and particles getting stuck in the air so you can randomly check the whole 64x64 chunk every once in a while. I think Noita does this when a thread runs out of work to do. This really does give you a massive performance boost even without multi threading and allows your sim to scale up to giant worlds. Here's my attempt to do this so far, the dirty rects are purple, hopefully they are visible.

[example video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1fnM.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

In the rectangle object, store two arrays: an X array and a Y array.  The Y array will store the number of sand pixels in each row.  The X array will store the number of sand pixels in each column.

Whenever you "paint" sand, check every pixel under the paintbrush.  If it is not sand already, increment both the X and Y arrays corresponding to that pixel as appropriate.  If it is sand already, do nothing.

When you erase sand, do the opposite.

Then, all you have to do when you erase sand is check whether the first or last value in the X and Y arrays are 0.  If so, check the next value, and so on, until you get a row or column that is not empty.  Then shrink the rectangle accordingly.

This strategy will make large paintbrushes *slightly* less efficient, but it can handle arbitrarily large rectangles without having to check every pixel.